# Spell correction improvement based on a set of letters with similar forms in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, ocr, spell-checking, spelling

I'm developing a spell corrector system for non-English language which works on OCR output. I use very large dictionaries to check spelling errors and give suggestions.

Most of spelling errors are because of letters which have similar form. For example `ـجـ` , `ـچـ` , `ـحـ` , `ـخـ` or `غ` , `ع` and etc. These letters exist in English too, for example `I`, `l` and `u`, `v` , `y`.

Spell checking system gives some suggestion for a word we want to check. For example if we input `voga` it'll suggest these words:

- `volga`
- `boga`
- `yoga`
- `toga`

Since the length of `voga` is 4, then we'll keep only 4-letter suggestions. Now because an OCR engine can detect `v` as `y` (because their forms are alike), we'll chose `yoga` as the best suggestion for `voga` as an OCR output.

In our language, this kind of selection is very effective. For example if we input `مدپر`, these words will be suggested:

- `مدارا`
- `مدار`
- `مدیر`
- `مراد`

Based on our sets (in this example: `ـبـ` , `ـپـ` , `ـیـ` and `ز` , `ر` , `ژ` and `ذ` , `د` and `مـ` , `فـ` ,  `قـ`) and word's length, `مدیر` would be best option for `مدپر`.

The way I usually implement this function in PHP scripting language is to keep words in same length which are suggested then create all possible combinations of the wrongly spelled word by replacing all sets (like `مدپر`, `فدپر`, `قدپر` and then `مذپر` , `فذپر` , `قذپر` and so on) and then searching for same word in the suggestions list. But this method of implementation is really slow (specially on a large context) and makes it almost useless.

What is the best method or algorithm to implement this kind of function in PHP?

**Update:**

The engines which produce suggestion lists are optimized and usually include the correct word in the suggestion list. The problem is that my system must select one of the suggestion as the correct word without any artificial intelligence. So I think this method is good in my language because there are many sets in which letters have similar form and this is why OCR engines usually detect words wrongly. But if there are better methods, you are welcomed to suggest them.

Comment: Please pardon me, but are you serious??? This is WAY too broad question. Solutions exists, but many scientists spent years on it, because it's an important topic. And you can definitely find hundreds of pages on this topic. So please do some own research, then come again and show your effort, show what you tried and what problems you need to solve in your next step.

Comment: @AlKepp The engines I use to get suggestions are optimized and almost give the correct word as one of their suggestions. The problem is that my system must select one of the suggestions automatically and selecting one of them using this method is really effective. I don't know how should I select the best one expect doing such thing.

Comment: @AlKepp I also updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think this question is too broad to be asked here. It still looks to me like you haven't any idea how to do it, so you should not ask for PHP solution. In my opinion this question is in the first place about algorithmic solution, not about the programming or implementation. I am sure many different solutions exist, and since we did a scientific research in this field some years ago, I am going to propose one solution to let you get some clue how you can do it.

Let's say you have an "OCR word" which is invalid and you want to select the best valid word to replace it from your dictionary of valid words.

1. Start with the standard suggestion algorithm. So you get a few candidate words.
2. Now compute the "distance" of these words to the OCR word.
3. Use the candidate with minimum computed distance.

The question now is how to compute the distance of two words. You can start with [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) - but this classic algorithm is not good enough for your situation and it will not do more than what you already have got from step 1, so you need to make something more suitable for you. Simply said you want to give some bonus for similar symbols/letters. We used a fuzzy automata to solve the very same situation for DNA analysis. It would be too long to write complete algorithm here, so please look at [our paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226699452_Approximate_String_Matching_by_Fuzzy_Automata) if you need more information. (The link goes to researchgate repository.)

You can also completely skip step 1 and create a global searching system for similar words with similarities, that is also described in our paper. I would vote for this global approach.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I needed. I'll read the entire article.

Comment: This is so complex! I can't understand it. Can you please write a simple programming algorithm for the research?